# Does ARC insert code in -dealloc before or after any custom -dealloc code?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

With ARC sometimes I still need to write a -dealloc method to do some cleanup. In some rare cases I need to refer to properties of the instance to properly do cleanup. Such as unregistering from NSNotificationCenter with a given sender object, which is owned and referenced by a property.

Does ARC insert it's property release code at the end of after my own code, or does it insert this at the beginning of -dealloc, before my own code?

If ARC would be inserting code before any custom -dealloc code, then this would be very dangerous since you can't access properties anymore if needed.

**This question is about where ARC inserts the property release code in a synthesized -dealloc, and not about wether or not to implement -dealloc.**

Comment: I think ARC is smart enough to detect and work with these cases.

Comment: Using property accessors in `dealloc` was a bad idea even before ARC. Just as it was a bad idea to use them in initialisers. use the iVars directly.

Comment: You're right. To clarify: Should ARC release properties before your own cleanup code, then using iVars directly won't help you much. The referenced object's could likely be gone then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC releases instance variables at the end of the dealloc chain. In other words, all the dealloc methods in the inheritance chain are run, and *then* any ARC-managed instance variables will be deallocated. You could think of it as happening in `-[NSObject dealloc]`, though it's really even later than that.

So rest assured; ARC won't release your properties out from under you in your `-dealloc` method. ARC won't release them until you have no way to reference them anymore.

Comment: Good and useful answer :-) Thank you so much! Can you point out some resources where you got that knowledge from? The point is it seems logical, but I want to be sure. Very sure.

Comment: I know it was mentioned in one of the WWDC sessions, but I'll see if I can find an exact reference.

Comment: The deallocation timeline was discussed in WWDC 2011's Session 322 - "Objective-C Advancements In Depth", in a section titled "Death of an Object", about 36 minutes in.

Answer (score 7):

I think, that everything is said here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.special_methods.dealloc

> 7.1.2. dealloc
>
> A program is ill-formed if it contains a message send or @selector expression for the selector dealloc.
>
> Rationale: there are no legitimate reasons to call dealloc directly.
>
> A class may provide a method definition for an instance method named dealloc. This method will be called after the final release of the object but before it is deallocated or any of its instance variables are destroyed. The superclass's implementation of dealloc will be called automatically when the method returns.
>
> Rationale: even though ARC destroys instance variables automatically, there are still legitimate reasons to write a dealloc method, such as freeing non-retainable resources. Failing to call [super dealloc] in such a method is nearly always a bug. Sometimes, the object is simply trying to prevent itself from being destroyed, but dealloc is really far too late for the object to be raising such objections. Somewhat more legitimately, an object may have been pool-allocated and should not be deallocated with free; for now, this can only be supported with a dealloc implementation outside of ARC. Such an implementation must be very careful to do all the other work that NSObject's dealloc would, which is outside the scope of this document to describe.

Comment: This is definitive, but if you want a more user-friendly explanation, watch the *Introducing Automatic Reference Counting* video from [WWDC 2011](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).

Comment: This does -by far- not answer my question. I did read this document myself. It does not tell wether or not ARC releases instance variables  at the end or at the beginning of -dealloc. ARC simply synthesizes dealloc, but when implementing it yourself, ARC has to insert that code somewhere. The question is *where*.

Comment: Why? Third paragraph states: "This method will be called after the final release of the object but before it is deallocated or any of its instance variables are destroyed. The superclass's implementation of dealloc will be called automatically when the method returns." So dealloc process is exactly the same as before.

Comment: This question was not about the -dealloc chain, but about where ARC inserts property release code inside -dealloc. In manual memory management you just released strong references in -dealloc and sometimes did some more cleanup. Now ARC synthesizes that, but the document you linked to does not tell exactly where that synthesis happens. It's about the property release code in -dealloc, not about -dealloc itself.

Comment: I did some research. It seems that it does not insert any releases in your code there. I presume that all deallocations and frees happen only in [NSObject dealloc]. That is called right in the end of the chain. So, once more, your code must be safe anyway. Do you have exact code that does not work or works wrong?